# Can't update dataSource with ListView on React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listview, react-native, datasource

I'm fetching my JSON data correctly and it is printing fine, however I cannot set it to the datasource of the list so I can update my rows correctly.  When printing the this.state.dataSource it is returning as undefined.  My returned JSON is an array.

```
export default class CoinCheckerRN extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
    this.state = {
        dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);

}

componentDidMount() {
    getCryptocurrencyData().then(function(result) {
        console.log('??????', result[0].name)
        this.setState({ dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(result)});
        console.log('??', this.state.dataSource);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('!!!!!', error)
    });



}

_renderRow(data) {
    return (
        <CoinCell coinName={'Bitcoin'} coinPrice={'£1,000'} coinPercentageChange={'-4.2%'}></CoinCell>        )
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                ref={'resultListView'}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(data) => this._renderRow(data)}
                renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
                renderHeader={() => <Header />}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you see anything at all in ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it with one of the previous answers listed here with a slight tweak:

```
 _getCoinData() {
    getCryptocurrencyData().then(function(result) {

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
        this.setState({
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(result),
            jsonData: result
        });

        console.log('!!!', this.state.jsonData);
    }.bind(this))
}
```